# How does an app get to be featured in the App Store?

Tags: itunes, ios, applications, ios-appstore

I have created an iOS Lifestyle app. In the App Store, under the **Top Featured** tab in the **New** column I was amazed to see my app listed there.

Is it organized by sales or Apple featured?

Comment: Also FYI I didnt get any sales for past two days.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the number of users viewing your app description, or possibly the number of downloads.  It could just as well be random or based on its age.  I don't think apple has documented this.

Comment: It might also be placed there when an Apple employee decides to feature it.

Comment: @rubix: If so, them im happy as this is my first app, released on feb 13th only.. Thanks

Comment: @rubixibuc Yes, I believe your second answer is correct. You should submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be placed there when an Apple employee decides to feature it.